# Linux Ubuntu - автоматическое восстановление интернет соединения

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Мне постоянно требуется удаленное подключение к Ubuntu на моем домашнем компьютере. Подключен он через Ethernet-провод. Но периодически, по какой-то причине на нем отваливается сеть и интернет становится недоступен, из-за чего я не могу к нему подключиться. Помогает переподелючение провода, но т.к. физически я нахожусь далеко, то не могу переподключать его.

Подскажите простое и надежное решение проблемы? Как заставить Ubuntu самой восстанавливать интернет-соединение?

Comment: возможно, нужно понять причину пропадания интернета и сам тип подключения. Для начала неплохо в момент пропадания интернета посмотреть вывод dmesg. А там может быть как просто "провайдер решил отключить на минутку" до "падение драйвера".

Comment: Скорее всего неисправность компа-сетевой платы-кабеля-роутера. Рецепт - найти неисправное устройство и заменить его. Вплоть до того, что переставить сетевую плату в соседний слот. Иногда помогает.

Comment: Выкинуть network manager, выключить hotplug, запретить system suspend и / или настроить WoL, если маршрутизатор умеет.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в крон задание, к примеру каждый час перезапускать сеть
Ifdown eth0 & &  Ifup eth0

Лучше небольшой скрипт, который будет пинговать гугл. /яндекс и в случае ошибки
Опять таки выполнять вышеуказанную последовательность комманд